# Does Instapaper allow sharing the Instapaper view without logging in?

Tags: instapaper

If I share Instapaper URLs with others, it just sends them to the original source page. Is there a way to send other people a link to the Instapaper view of an article?

Comment: I’m sure there is (was) a way, but I can’t find it at the moment.

Comment: You could always send the [Mobilizer](http://mobilizer.instapaper.com/m) link. (E.g.: http://mobilizer.instapaper.com/m?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.newyorker.com%2Fmagazine%2F2015%2F02%2F23%2Fwizards-sound)

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Instapaper report and received the following response:

> Thanks for writing in. At the moment, there's no way to share the
>   Instapaper view version of a text, as that is for registered users of
>   Instapaper. Sorry for any inconvenience this may cause. Cheers!

So the workaround of using the [Mobilizer](http://mobilizer.instapaper.com/m) option @Alex mentioned is probably the best alternative.